# print long string in xcode 6 debugging console

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am getting only 1022 characters of my String to display in the debugging console of Xcode6. The actual length is around 2500 characters.

Is there a way to display all character in the console or do i have to write them in a file.

i have tried `print` in the console but that displays only 1023 characters.

First i tried with `println(sqlstatement)`, that did not work. Second, as mentioned above, i used `print sqlstatement` in the debug console itself. Oh and debugger is *lldb*.

Regards Adarkas

Comment: I printed a 3000 character string, and it printed :/

Comment: With out the code how you are posting we can not tell what is going on. So post the code where you printing the string.

Comment: edited my question and thanks for the help. How did you print your string @VinayJain?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to your comment @nms. The command line for lldb is

```
setting set target.max-string-summary-length 10000
```

with 10000 being the number of characters that are printed.

I haven`t found a nicer way to set this setting for lldb, other than typing it every time i debug, than to set a breakpoint in AppDelegate to auto continue and adding the above command to it.

Comment: To run it by default, add this command to `~/.lldbinit` file. As explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242547/2505726