# How to change default LLDB settings

Tags: xcode, lldb

From time to time I need to print long string using LLDB. Default LLDB setting trims printed string, and I have to type in this thing:

```
set set target.max-string-summary-length 10000
```

When doing next run this setting isn't persisted. Is there a way to set it so that all subsequent LLDB debugging sessions will respect this setting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well solution is quite simple. First create file `~/.lldbinit` and then put there commands you wish to be run when LLDB starts, in my case:

```
set set target.max-string-summary-length 10000
```