# How to print equivalent of #line #file #function in LLDB using Swift?

Tags: swift, lldb

In source code, if I do:

```swift
print("\(#file) \(#line) \(#function)")
```

I get output like:

```
MyFile.swift 31 doFoo()
```

However, from a breakpoint in LLDB, if I do similar:

```
(lldb) po "\(#file) \(#function) \(#line)"
```

I get:

```
"<EXPR> $__lldb_expr(_:) 6"
```

Is there a way to get output like the former from the latter? I'm aware you can do:

```
(lldb) frame info
frame #0: 0x0000000102d92c46 MyApp `closure #2 in Client.fetchCart($0=(error_instance = 0x0000600000810be0 -> 0x0000000108e88cc0 (void *)0x0000000108e88ce8: __SwiftNativeNSError)) at Client+Cart.swift:21:23
```

... but that output is pretty messy. Is there a way to clean it up to just file, line and function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [set a custom format](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/formatting.html#format-strings) for displaying the frame info. For what you want, you can do:

```
settings set frame-format "${line.file.basename} ${line.number} ${function.name-without-args}\n"
```

And then try `frame info`. You'd get something like:

```
AppDelegate.swift 11 AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
```

You can make this setting permanent by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40242547/5133585).

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for