# How to let local .png image convert to base64 string

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, base64

I try to convert my png image to base64 string.
But I use my output base64 string in consolog and paste to online tool website.
It just show the top of image, not complete image.

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

```
UIImage *uiImageInstance = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImageInstance);
NSString *base64Str = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSLog(@"base64Str : %@", base64Str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString * base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr Let me know if this works for you. And also let me know if you want more information from me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, it's the same. But I think the reason is consolog don't print all base64 string. Why?

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr See this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404961/11327526)

Comment: ok thanks. If I pass my base64String to server site, the base64String is complete or truncated? I afraid it's not complete and send to server site.

Comment: As I tried this code with one demo image that is full text of base64 string.

Comment: For check code is working or not use small size image file and if that code is working fine then whatever the file is, You just have to store it in any variable. Thanks